# Maximum Value of $\frac {\sin^3x\cos x}{\tan^2x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the maximum value of the following function? $$f(x)=\frac {\sin^3x\cos x}{\tan^2x+1}$$

I'm just not sure where I start. I have no requisite knowledge on finding the maximum values of any function.

And just a side question, is it possible to find the maximum/minimum of any function?

Comment: Note $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$. No, it's not possible. **Any** just covers too much territory.

Comment: $\tan^2 x+1=\sec^2 x$,Then it turns to be $ \sin^3 x \cos^3 x$,  I think you can do it.

Comment: Or, what's the maximum of $s^3c^3$ (or maximum of $sc$) where $s^2+c^2=1$? (Silly me, just saw the answer, the bit that introduces $2x$!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac { \sin ^{ 3 } x\cos  x }{ \tan ^{ 2 } x+1 } =\frac { \sin ^{ 3 } x\cos  x }{ \frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  } =\sin ^{ 3 }{ x\cos ^{ 3 }{ x } = } { \left( \frac { \sin { 2 } x }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 3 }=\frac { 1 }{ 8 } \sin ^{ 3 }{ 2x } $$ so max is ...

Comment: Darn, you beat me there.  :D

Comment: Is there a general formula or some technique you can use to find the maximum/minimum of any function?

Comment: I don't think so,it was  just useful  in this case